# Link List From a File , different format for each input in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm looking for some information about how to write from a file  to a link list

Let's say that I have a file.txt that look like this:

```
Jen    Red
12     25
14     18
58     19
0 0

Marie  Blue
25     56
0 0

Nancy  Purple
556    621
111    2
1      141
114    2
0 0
```

I would like to write this into a linked List

We first start to write the name and color. After that we need to input some data but each person have different numbers of input. We terminated the link list by `0 0` and we repeated the process for a different person.

Where can a look for more infos about this ?

Comment: Use `std::cin` and a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to write this into a linked list

How?  Is each person its own node, or is each person its own linked list?

What exactly are you trying to do with the information?  How you plan to process the information can affect which data structure best fits your app.

> We terminated the link list by `0 0` and we repeated the process for a different person.

That's just a `while` loop.

> Where can a look for more infos about this ?

[Here is documentation on std::list.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) [Here's a specific kind of list, std::queue.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)